# iPhone can't sync with Mac saying there isn't enough space but there is

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization

This problem started today when I went to sync the music from my computer(MacBook Pro 16" M1 Pro Sonoma) with my iPhone(12PM 512GB), and I got this message:

"The iPhone “MyiPhoneName” cannot be synced because there is not enough free space to hold all of the items on your Mac (additional 7.69 GB required)."

The thing is, the iPhone has 143.72GB available, so what gives? It's almost like it wants to copy over my entire music library again(which is 151.05GB in size), but the songs are already on the phone, I just want to sync the newest 2-3 songs I added to my library, there's no need to have free space for a double copy of my library, it never asked for it before.

I never synced the phone with another computer, just this one, and the music library is the one from this computer.

Comment: how much space is there left on your macbook?

Comment: I also want to add that the backup is done through iCloud and not on the Mac and that the iPhone is updated to the latest iOS, which as of now is 17.2.1

Comment: @theonlygusti about 144GB but I've noticed that the space it requires to sync shrinks when I delete stuff from my phone so I think it's talking about the iPhone space.

Comment: Your iPhone has 143.72GB left of 512GB, which means your iPhone has 370 GB of storage used? No wonder your computer, which only has 144GB free, can't back up the 370GB iPhone

Comment: What exactly do you sync?

Comment: The only things I sync are the entire music library and the Favorites album from the Photos app(very small in size, 40ish pictures), nothing else. Backup, Contacts, Calendars are going through iCloud

Comment: @theonlygusti The OP is not asking about backing up the phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like unsyncing and deleting the music library on the iPhone and syncing it again solved the issue.

Now I have 145GB free on the phone and a 153,5GB music library and it syncs fine.